# Insert into select with order by for special case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to insert into my temp table the latest date that is less than my input date (2016-02-23). According to me the order by is necessary in the select statement.

The `order by` in the below query is causing an error. How can I change this query so that I can insert the latest date less than the input date?

Any ideas ?

```
INSERT INTO #tempEffDate(EffDate) 
    (SELECT TOP (1) EffDate 
     FROM ProductTable 
     WHERE EffDate < '2016-02-23' 
     ORDER BY effdate)
```

Comment: Instead of top 1 / order by, which can be confusing because people might assume the order by has some bearing on the order rows are inserted, why don't you just use MIN()?

Comment: What should happen if there are no rows matching the condition? Insert no row or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it a subquery. I am guessing the error is that you can't have an order by in a subquery...of course posting that would be helpful.

```
INSERT INTO #tempEffDate(EffDate) 
SELECT TOP (1) EffDate 
FROM ProductTable 
WHERE EffDate < '2016-02-23' 
ORDER BY effdate
```